# npm ERR! code ENOENT and npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I've installed the latest version of nodejs (12.16.3 LTS) and is working fine but not npm, I can type:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

and get the following results

```
v12.16.3
6.14.5
```

I can even do `npm help` and it shows all the commands, but when I try to do anything else with npm I always get the following errors:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I'm running on windows 10 and I dont know what else to do. I did the `PATH` thing, it looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Josian>echo %PATH%

C:\Users\Josian\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Python38\Scripts\;
C:\Python38\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Restart the machine once.

Comment: I've restarted the machine multiple time.

Comment: You may need to uninstall node once.

Comment: Can you verify that `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` file actually exists?

Comment: Yes, node.ext should exist.

Comment: Yes, it exists. I've even opened node.exe manually to verify that its working.

Comment: I haven't been able to solve this issue, if someone can attempt to at least give me a possible solution, I would be grateful.