# NodeJs ENOENT error on all commands regardless of some working

Tags: node.js, enoent

Nodejs throwing error ENOENT on all commands. It is acting as though it is uninstalled but it allows some commands. I can run --version, install dependencies, help. For example;

npm --version
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.1.0

Full error when trying to run dev

```
32 verbose stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs ENOENT
32 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
32 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
32 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
33 verbose pkgid corf@1.6.0
34 verbose cwd D:\projectfolder
35 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
36 verbose node v20.9.0
37 verbose npm  v10.1.0
38 error code ENOENT
39 error syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs
40 error path D:\projectfolder
41 error errno -4058
42 error enoent spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs ENOENT
43 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
43 error enoent
44 verbose exit -4058
```

Fixes that haven't worked
Change the path to the install folder
Change path to System32
Restart vscode
Restart pc
Yarn is incompatible with this project so cannot switch
Installing different versions of npm

One of the solutions I found was formatting the pc but that is not possible for me.

These are some other questions on this but none of those answers have worked for me:
[All npm commands giving same error (ENOENT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962195/all-npm-commands-giving-same-error-enoent)

[npm ERR! code ENOENT and npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766864/npm-err-code-enoent-and-npm-err-syscall-spawn-c-program-files-nodejs-node-exe)

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/2366

I had initially thought it was a pathing issue but I have changed the path multipul times and have the same errors.

Comment: I would like to note moving to a new pc has solved the issue but that's not a viable solution in most cases.

This question is probably best answered here but I couldn't implement all of the solutions suggested to solve this. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js?rq=2